# React Component is not rerendered after a prop change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Today in ***SorninHeadachePost*** we have a new React render that doesn't occur.

I'll try to explain as best as I can and give maximum informations (do not hesitate if you think something is missing).

SO !

I have a React component named `Navigation` that should re-render once it's props change.

```js
    //[...]
    const [availableViews, setAvailableViews] = useState(props.availableViews)
    const [userViews, setUserViews] = useState(props.userViews)
    const [_, forceUpdate] = useReducer((x) => x + 1, 0);

    useEffect(() => {
        setAvailableViews(props.availableViews)
    }, [props.availableViews])

    useEffect(() => {
        setUserViews(props.userViews)
        console.log("the log")
        forceUpdate()
    }, [props.userViews])

    return (
        <div className="navigation-root">
                <div className="navigation-title">
                    <img src={dashboardSVG} alt="Dashboard"/>
                    <span className="navigation-titleSpan">DASHBOARD</span>
                </div>
                <div className="navigation-tabContainer">
                    {
                        props.dataInitialized && availableViews.length > 0
                            ?
                            availableViews.map((d:ViewObject, key:any) => {
                                if (d.viewName.startsWith("Default ")) {
                                    let views: ViewObject[] = []
                                    for (let i = 0; i<userViews.length;i++) {
   //[...]
```

In this code snippet that represent the React component `Navigation`, the prop `userViews` changes on a user action, the log (`the log`) is being thrown on this action, so the prop is updated.

But nothing change....

May it be because the logic that use the state `userViews` is wrapped into a `.map` callback. (If it's because of this, how can it be rerendered)

As you can see I tried the hack of the reducer to forceupdate. Nothing changes either.

At this point I'm looking for a full rerender of this component so it updates all child components.

Comment: Using correct terminology is important so that everyone can understand what you mean. "Hooks" are not "components", they are ways of interacting with the component lifecycle, holding state, or other features of a component. The function `Navigation` is a "component".

Comment: According to your sayings, I miss-used the hook term. I edit this, thank you.

Comment: Have you checked (e.g. with React Devtools) that the component truly _hasn't rerendered_ as opposed to it just looking like it hasn't? The former implies that the props/state of the component hasn't truly changed (which would be weird indeed since your `console.log` is still called), and the latter that your code simply doesn't output what you _think_ it should output. Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem in e.g. CodeSandbox?

Comment: If the `userViews` prop is *actually* a new prop reference/value it should have already triggered a rerender on its own. If you enqueue a state update `setUserViews(props.userViews)` that is a new state reference/value this will also have triggered a rerender. There's no need for the `forceUpdate` at all if your code is correctly updating this `userViews` value in the parent component.